# Replace first character in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

Am trying to replace the first character of a string. I can replace specific characters using `replace()` function. But not sure how to replace the *first* character of all strings in a column.

Sample data:

```
Column1
43449927
13448927
53443457
```

Expected result after replacing first character with '7':

```
Column1
73449927
73448927
73443457
```

Comment: This is not valid PostgreSQL, but, `UPDATE table SET Column1 = CONCAT("7", SUBSTRING(Column1, 1))` is the basic logic. Instead of _replacing_ the first value with something, concatenate "7" and then a substring (all but the first character) together.

Comment: This is concatenating 7 with existing values

Comment: I'm not familiar with Postgres syntax, but it looks like you'd use `substring(Column1 from 2)` to get all but the first character, and then concatenate "7" to that for a result of `"7" || substring(Column1 from 2)`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html. It looks like this function is 1-based instead of 0-based, so try `Column1 from 2`.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones, but thanks for the idea, i got the solutions to achieve it

Comment: You might also consider the `overlay()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below syntax helped me,

```
'7' || substr(column1, 2, length(column1))
```

Comment: There is really no need to for the 2nd function parameter in this case. @pifor provided the superior form.

Answer (score 1):

For character data:

```
update mytable set data= '7' || substr(mycolumn, 2);
```

Comment: This is also concatenating 7 with existing values

Comment: I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[`right()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) with a *negative* offset** is shortest and fastest:

```
'7' || right(column1, -1)
```

`replace()` is not smart enough to take a *position* as pattern. Would have to be `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(column1, '^.', '7')
```

But regular expressions are more expensive.

Subtle difference: The latter returns an empty string (`''`) for empty string input, as there is nothing to *replace*. If that's the behavior you need, and you still want best performance, wrap the first in a (cheap!) `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN column1 <> ''
     THEN '7' || right(column1, -1)
     ELSE column1 END
```

As point of reference: in a quick test on Postgres 12 on Linux, the expression with `right()` was ...

- ~ 10 % faster than with added `CASE`.
- ~ 25 % faster than `substr()` with only the "from" parameter.
- ~ 2x as fast `substr()` with redundant "count" parameter (length).
- ~ 3x as fast as `overlay(column1 PLACING '7' FROM 1)`.
- ~ 10x as fast as `regexp_repace()`.

Test matrix with extended test case in a *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=83e1876542bdb023ff847bbadf41fce9)*